# Should I reset $wp_query?

Tags: wp-query, loop, query, query-posts

I am not totally new on WordPress but the query thing is a bit confusing to me. I searched the web and read a lot of articles, but I couldn't find what I needed. Maybe it could help a lot of people who have WordPress skills like me.

I want to create a shortcode and I need to loop through a custom post type called events.

```
function leweb_get_suggested_events() {

    // Query
    global $wp_query;

    // Arguments  
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'events',
    );  

    ob_start();

    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if( $query->have_posts() ) {
        echo '<ul>';
        while( $query->have_posts() ) {
            $query->the_post();
            echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    }

    $output = ob_get_clean();
    return $output;

}
add_shortcode( 'leweb_suggested_events', 'leweb_get_suggested_events' );
```

The query is right and its working. But should I reset something?

I call the global `$wp_query` to get in the main loop. This is what I found out on reading some articles.

Then I start my own loop with `$query = new WP_Query($args);`
So I have two loops right? The main loop and my own loop.

**Should I reset them both or just one of them, or is it fine like above?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The query is right and its working. But should I reset something?

Yes!

> Should I reset them both or just one of them, or is it fine like above?

**Neither!**

Your `WP_Query` object is self contained in `$query`, so there's no reason to touch the `$wp_query` global variable, why would you? `$wp_query` represents the main query, so leave it alone.

What you need to reset, is the current post. Notice `$query->the_post()` sets the current post, you need to undo that after the loop ends:

```php
    if( $query->have_posts() ) {
        while( $query->have_posts() ) {
            $query->the_post();
            ....
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }
```

### A Word on `wp_reset_query()`

The `wp_reset_query()` function is something you might see in your research, but avoid this. It's intended to clean up after `query_posts`, which is a function you should never use.

If you ever find yourself needing to use `query_posts`, or `wp_reset_query` in your client work, something has gone terribly wrong. Scrub these from your memory, scream when you see them in code, and refactor them with extreme predjudice.

### Shortcodes and Blocks

Have you considered turning this into a GB block instead of a shortcode? Just create a block that's rendered in PHP, there's no need to learn React or advanced JS

Comment: Thank you Tom for this perfect answer!!! What do you mean with GB block?

Comment: A block in the new block editor that got added in WP 5.0

Comment: Do you have any serious source, where i can read about it?